# Photon Server: Can client and server app send messages to each other without the client joining any room in server?

Tags: c#, photon

I need the client to query some game settings in a room before joining it. Do photon already have this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a room, the client can set custom room properties, which can be made visible to the lobby, too. An example for this can be found in our [Matchmaking Guide](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/manuals-and-demos/matchmaking-and-lobby) in the subsection 'Room Properties and the Lobby'.